# Larger alternative to default UITextfield font that looks GOOD

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

In interface builder i've created a UITextfield within a subclass of a UITableViewCell.

The default font is just too small. If I make it bigger in interface builder it looks a bit ugly. Not as crisply rendered. I'd like a font similar to that used in the addressBook application when you edit a contact. The text their is bigger than the default and display nice.

Anyone got a good font/style/size? And I should set this in IB right?

The UITextfield class states: @property(nonatomic,retain) UIFont  *font;  // default is nil. use system font 12 pt

Does this mean they only want you to use size 12?

Thanks!
**edit: The larger font looks crisp when it is selected to be edited but looks slightly distorted when not being edited. In the image below EC1V is first responder (and therefore good quality) whereas the url below is not firstresponder and is bad quality. (cached image?)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I think I've figured it out. Basically some font sizes eg (Helevetica 13,14) Just dont display pretty. I'm using helvetica 15 which looks crisp. there's just a bit of trial and error involved in getting the right display.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran into exactly the same fuzzy glitch.